# How to find out if there are any not committed or pushed changes to a mercurial repository from bash?

Tags: mercurial, diff

I want to incorporate this logic to a bash script: to stop processing if the current repository has any local changes.

I do have the same logic for git, put now I need to for mercurial:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
git pull
git update
# Disallow unstaged changes in the working tree
    if ! git diff-files --check --exit-code --ignore-submodules -- >&2
    then
        echo >&2 "error: you have unstaged changes."
        exit 1
    fi

# Disallow uncommitted changes in the index
    if ! git diff-index --cached --exit-code -r --ignore-submodules HEAD -- >&2
    then
        echo >&2 "error: your index contains uncommitted changes."
        exit 1
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
if [ -n "$(hg status -mar)" ]
then
    echo >&2 "error: your index contains uncommitted changes."
    exit 1
fi
```

That checks for any files moved, added, or removed.  If you want to check for deleted (missing) or unknown but not ignored you can do that too.

Comment: I do want to check for everything, including deleted files and even commited files that were not pushed to the upper repository. I need to be sure that when this succeeds I do have a perfect copy of the remote repository, as I want to make this a requirement for pushing a release.